# How to restrict HttpTraceFilter path?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using `spring-actuator` and want to restrict the path for trace request/response logging. Tried as follows, but still all paths invoked are logged to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/httptrace`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(HttpTraceFilter.class)
public FilterRegistrationBean traceFilterRegistration(HttpTraceFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setUrlPatterns("/test/*"));
    return registration;
}
```

In the httptrace endpoint, I still see request to eg `http://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings` or `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico`. But those should be hidden due to my mapping url pattern, shouldn't they?

Sidenote: I noticed that when leaving out the `@ConditionalOnBean` it works as expected with restricted path. Probably this has to do with initialization order of the trace filter...

Comment: Please post your answer if this is resolved

Answer (score 0):

To intercept request as per your requirement, you can do it like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler){
    //your custom logic here.
    return true;
}
}
```

Then register here to intercept your required path:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
    registry.addInterceptor(new 
CustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/actuator/**","/test/**");
}
}
```

Comment: And how can I tie your answer to the existing actuator endpoint `HttpTraceFilter`? I don't see the connection here...